# ERROR Connection refused: Grails email verification using mail plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

i am new to Grails.
i  am using mail 1.0 pluguin..
i configured config file as below

```
    grails {
        mail {
            host = "smtp.gmail.org"
            port = 465
            username = "myaccount@gmail.com"
            password = "mypassword"
            props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
        }
    }
```

and used sendMail() in controller as below

```
 sendMail {
            to "myanotheraccount@gmail.com"
            subject "New User Confirmation"
            body "how are u"
        }
```

I have no firewall issues.
but it show s error as Connection refused.......???

Answer (score 1):

Probably a configuration issue, have you looked at this example which shows how to use Mailgun via SMTP: https://github.com/jbayer/mail-java